# Use of a microphone is Asp.Net application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, client-side, microphone

Since SilverLight doesn't natively supports the use of microphone, is there a workaround I can use to get a live stream of what the user said in his microphone.

I need to access to a audio stream (from the user client microphone) that a server class (c#) will use.

I look to use Flash or Java applet, but it's all seems to be pretty difficult to output the audio stream in a way my Asp.Net application can use it ...

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require software to be installed on the client (such as Flash or Java) that can access the sound drivers / APIs from the client operating system.

With Flash, this requires use of [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/). Research sending an audio stream from the Flash player to the FMS.